# How to place a pie chart based on data frame in Tkinter frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, user-interface, tkinter, pie-chart

I'm trying to place a pie chart inside the Tkinter frame with an absolute positioning.
How do I place the pie at the upper left side of the frame?

[image]

**So far I tried:**

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import datetime as dt
import time
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Dashboard:

    def __init__(self, filterdDf):

        self.filterdDf = filterdDf

        root =Tk()
        root.title('Dashboard')
        root.geometry('1300x1000')
        root.resizable(False, False)

        frame = Frame(root, width=1000, height=680)
        frame.configure(background="gray28")
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        frameChartsLT = Frame(root)
        frameChartsLT.pack()

        fig = Figure()  # create a figure object
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # add an Axes to the figure

        ax.pie(filterdDf[('Sum', '')], radius=1, shadow=True)

        chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, frameChartsLT)
        chart1.get_tk_widget().pack()

        root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could have just edited that in not written in comments.

Comment: also did You pack that figure?

Comment: @Matiiss yes it's packed. I edited the code now. please see the newly added picture.

Comment: did You set the parent as that frame? so if You use pack what I suggest is that You pack the frame like this `fram_name.pack(side='left', fill='y')` and pack the widget inside like this `widget _name.pack(side='top')`. if doesn't work try adding `expand=True` to the packing arguments tho it should work without it, the frame maybe can even fill both if You need so

Comment: @Matiiss I've added:  frameChartsLT.place(x=350, y=320) and it works! thanks!

Comment: it isn't the best way to place widgets on window but if it works it works (better is to use `.pack()` or `.grid()`) (reason why it is not the best because of changing window later or packing other stuff)

Comment: @Matiiss do you got an Idea how I manage to set the background color of the figure? In the code above I wrote: frame.configure(background="gray28") and it worked to the main frame. I'm not sure where it should be written in the figure/frame in order to make it look more embeded. Thanks.

Comment: well me neither, I have no idea about anything related to matplotlib so I guess You will have to find some docs on that one